# A set of Linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$S = \{T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3:T\text{ is a linear transformation with }T(1,0,1)=(1,2,3),T(1,2,3)=(1,0,1)\}$$
Then S is:

(a) a singleton set

(b) a finite set containing more than one element

(c) a countably finite set

(d) an uncountable set

Comment: What have you done, what have you tried, ideas, insights, self work...?

Comment: pls tell me the true option

Comment: First, you already have an answer, given without you making a minimal effort to show that you've taken some time to think and solve the problem, which seems to be homework. This is not how SE is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an uncountable set because you can choose another vector $v$ to form $\{(1,0,1),(1,2,3),v\}$ a basis and so for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exist, in fact unique, $T \in S$ such than $T(v) = (x,0,0)$.